# Can't get my search icon to sit next to the search text area

Tags: html, css, button, search

I'm sure this is something simple but i'm exhausted trying to figure it out. I've tried a lot of different variations and I just can't get the search button to sit on the same line as the search bar. I'm at my wits end. Why are they on two different lines???

```css
.container-inner {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
  
#search-bar {
    width: 90%;
    border: 2px solid #fff200;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    outline: none;
    color: #9DBFAF;
}
  
#search-bar:focus{
    color: black;
}
  
.searchButton {
    width: 40px;
    height: 36px;
    border: 2px solid #fff200;
    background: grey;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.searchButton:hover{
    background: darkslategrey
}
  
.container {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-inner">
    <form id="search-form">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input id="search-bar" class="form-control search-bar" placeholder="Search for a song...">
            <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
            <i class="fa fa-search"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `button` is not a self closing tag, `input` misses the `/` to close, there's an extra `div` tag  being closed inside `<form>` that should be outside. Beside those problems, you can add `display: flex` to `.input-group` to try to solve your question

Comment: Thank you, I still haven't solved the button problem but I really appreciate you pointing out my oversights. I'm still new at this so i'm making a lot of bone head mistakes. Appreciated.

Comment: Use some tools to keep code clean of problems, html validator is important: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 1):

You should change add a wrapper with display `flex`, set the property flex of `#search-bar` to `1` and remove the height from the `#search-bar` as in the following example.

```css
 .container-inner {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

#search-bar {
    border: 2px solid #fff200;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    outline: none;
    color: #9DBFAF;
    flex: 1;
}

#search-bar:focus {
    color: black;
}

.searchButton {
    width: 40px;
    height: 36px;
    border: 2px solid #fff200;
    background: grey;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.searchButton:hover {
    background: darkslategrey
}

.container {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.input-wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-inner">
        <form id="search-form">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg input-wrapper">
                <input id="search-bar" class="form-control search-bar" placeholder="Search for a song...">
                <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `.input-group` `display: flex;`

```css
.container-inner {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
  
#search-bar {
    width: 90%;
    border: 2px solid #fff200;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    outline: none;
    color: #9DBFAF;
}
  
#search-bar:focus{
    color: black;
}
  
.searchButton {
    width: 40px;
    height: 36px;
    border: 2px solid #fff200;
    background: grey;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.searchButton:hover{
    background: darkslategrey
}

.input-group{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-inner">
    <form id="search-form">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input id="search-bar" class="form-control search-bar" placeholder="Search for a song...">
            <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
            <i class="fa fa-search"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your width on searchBar of `width: 90%;` is taking up too much space. 90% of the parent + it's own padding is leaving less than `40px;` needed for the button to sit alongside. Remove the width of the `searchBar` or make it less like 70% etc.

```css
.container-inner {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
  
#search-bar {
    border: 2px solid #fff200;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    outline: none;
    color: #9DBFAF;
}
  
#search-bar:focus{
    color: black;
}
  
.searchButton {
    width: 40px;
    height: 36px;
    border: 2px solid #fff200;
    background: grey;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.searchButton:hover{
    background: darkslategrey
}
  
.container {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-inner">
    <form id="search-form">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input id="search-bar" class="form-control search-bar" placeholder="Search for a song...">
            <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
            <i class="fa fa-search"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

try changing that display attribute for the inner container

Comment: This is not an answer, if you want to say something like this make it a comment.